# SoapUI sending double SOAP request

Tags: soap, soapui

I'm using SoapUI 5.2.0 (the free version) to test among other things a API Gateway.

While testing it, I noticed that the log in the API GW registers two requests every time I submit a single SOAP request from SoapUI.

I ran a test client consuming the same service through the API GW, and only a single request was registered.

When googling this issue, all I find it someone never answered about a similar problem when posting REST from SoapUI 3.something.
I have tried turning the switch between using pre-emptively authentication and not - and it only toogles a initial first repeat of the request, rejected with a request for auth.
(Basically that just changes the amount of requests between 3 and 2, instead of 2 and 1)

I fail to find any reference to this being a "feature" in SoapUI.

Why is it doing this double posting?
Can it turned off?

Has anybody else registered this behavior in SoapUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some further digging, it turned out that SoapUI had proxy set to "Automatic".
When I toggled it to "None", the issue of double posting disappeared.

I do not fully understand why a proxy would somehow result in double SOAP requests being sent to the service, but at least in my case it seems very much to be exactly what is going on.

So - if you came here with a similar problem, go check the "Proxy Settings" tab in "SoapUI Preferences" (File -> Preferences or Ctrl+Alt-P - at least in SoapUI 5.2.0).